# How do I read strings into a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I have a file with a series of random A's, G's, C's and T's in them that look like this:

```
>Mary
ACGTACGTACGTAC
>Jane
CCCGGCCCCTA
>Arthur
AAAAAAAAAAT
```

I took those letters and concatinated them to end up with `ACGTACGTACGTACCCCGGCCCCTAAAAAAAAAAT`. I now have a series of positions within that concatenated sequence that are of interest to me, and I want to find the associated Names that match with those positions (coordinates). I'm using the Perl function length to calculate the legnth of each sequence, and then associate the culmulative length with the name in a hash.
So far I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $seq_input = $ARGV[0]; 
my $coord_input = $ARGV[1]; 
my %idSeq; #Stores sequence and associated ID's.

open (my $INPUT, "<$seq_input") or die "unable to open $seq_input";
open (my $COORD, "<$coord_input") or die "unable to open $fcoord_input";

while (<$INPUT>) {
    if ($_ = /^[AGCT/) {
    $idSeq{$_

my $id = ( /^[>]/) 

#put information into a hash
#loop through hash looking for coordinates that are lower than the culmulative length

foreach $id
 $totallength = $totallength + length($seq)
 $lengthId{$totalLength} = $id
foreach $position
 foreach $length
  if ($length >= $position) { print; last }

close $fasta_input;
close $coord_input;
print "Done!\n";
```

So far I'm having trouble reading the file into a hash. Also would I need an array to print the hash?

Comment: I think you lost a large part of your code when pasting it into the question. Please revise it. This is not even close to compiling.

Comment: @simbabque Given the history of the questioner I don't think we will get any more information. He accepted only one of a dozen given answers and doesn't respond to comments.

Comment: @PerlDuck I know. But we can't do anything about that. You probably were not around back then, but I remember there was a time when it showed the questions to accepted answers ratio somewhere (maybe the profile), and we reminded people to please accept answers first before asking new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely clear on what you want; maybe this:

```
my $seq;
my %idSeq;
while ( my $line = <$INPUT> ) {
    if ( my ($name) = $line =~ /^>(.*)/ ) {
        $idSeq{$name} = length $seq || 0;
    }
    else {
        chomp $line;
        $seq .= $line;
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
$seq = 'ACGTACGTACGTACCCCGGCCCCTAAAAAAAAAAAT';
%idSeq = (
      'Mary' => 0,
      'Jane' => 14,
      'Arthur' => 25,
);
```