# How do I store culmultive length of strings into an array with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file which has a series of lines that are made up of A's, C's, G's and T's. I want to find the length of those lines, make a list of the culmultive lengths (adding the lengths together sequentially), and putting that into an array. So far I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my %idSeq;
my (@ID, @Seq);

open (my $INPUT, "<$input") or die "unable to open $input";

while (<$INPUT>) {
    if (my $culm_length = /^([AGCT]\w+)\n$/) {
    length($culm_length) = $_;  
    push (@Seq, $1);

    }    
}
bla bla bla....
```

So far I think what I have written gives me an array of the length of individual lines. I want the culmultive lengths, any ideas?

Comment: `length($culm_length) = $_;`? That doens't even compile!

Comment: Trivia: The 4 lvalue ops: `keys`, `substr`, `vec` and `$#a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to your previous question [*How do I read strings into a hash in Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723596/how-do-i-read-strings-into-a-hash-in-perl) which was put on hold, I think perhaps you want a *running total* of the lengths of the lines

I would write it this way. It keeps the running total in `$total` and pushes its value onto the `@lengths` array every time it changes

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( $input ) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $input or die qq{unable to open "$input" for input: $!};

my @lengths;
my $total = 0;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    push @lengths, $total += length $1 if /^([ACGT]+)/;
}
```

Comment: This is a good interpretation, given an index or query based on absolution position of well known locations.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $length = 0;
while (<>) {
   $length += length($1) if /^([AGCT]\w+)$/;
}

my @length = $length;  # But why would you want to do this?!

...
```

Comment: Shouldn't that  be:$length += length($_) if /^([AGCT])+\w+$/;  So that you trim off the trailing white space in the saved field..

Comment: @BenPen, No, they ask for the cumulative lengths of the *lines*. (I don't know why they keep saying "cumulative lengths" instead of "cumulative length", though.)

Comment: @BenPen, `\w+` doesn't match white space. You'd use `/^([AGCT]+\w+)\s*$/` to allow ignorable trailing whitespace (or you'd first "chomp" using something like `s/\s+\z//;`).

Comment: Ah good point, and you must, since it's being read from a file and will have EOL.

Comment: @BenPen, No, you need not. `$` is equivalent to `(?=\n\z)|\z` (when `/m` isn't used).

Comment: Wow.  Learned something today, That's an interesting alternative to chomp/chop.

Comment: His other question has a larger problem statement.  It's ok.  if you use $1 it'll work.  Just not a pattern of operation that I'm used to, so I have to soak it in.  Sorry.

Comment: I usually `chomp;` or `s/\s+\z//;` first as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it doesn't compile. I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax and posted here for help. (Is this why my question is currently sitting on -5?) –

Comment: The intent of all questions here is to be valuable additions to the catalog of good questions to ask about programming.   Clean up for clarity and you may get a few back.  for instance.  culm_length is not cumulative.  It's better $line_length.  /yxza/ in a scalar context does not return a length as well...

Comment: @BigPen: If you don't see it then please take it in faith that commenting here on any given programming language is a very bad idea. It's a huge stretch to read *tricky* as *interesting*, and there are dozens of languages that "look like C but aren't". We have Ç#, Java, Go, JavaScript, PHP, R etc. and I believe the similarities are much more interesting and useful than the differences. I think you shouldn't impose your viewpoint on *that C programmer*, but either way Stack Overflow is not the forum to discuss this. This dialogue is well off-topic, and will probably be deleted before long.

Comment: (The thread did already disappear, point taken, perhaps our culture differences amplified it..  Tricky is not as negative in the US, I think...)

Comment: @BenPen: You're very out of touch with your native language! Take a look a [Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tricky)

Comment: @Borodin Hmm, perhaps.  I may just never use the negative bits.  The meaning that I usually attribute to tricky is this: If you are good, you know your stuff, you are skillful.  In that definition there's "requiring skill" which is what I mean.  In many programming languages there are things where you have to know your stuff and use the features that are unique to the language, not the features common to all languages;  Cases where the implications of a parsing or library functionality are not immediately obvious, but skilled practitioners of the language commonly use them effectively.

Comment: To be a good programmer, skill is definitely required.  Using any programming language to it's full potential is not easy.